# HTML,CSS - body exceeds screen horizontally for unknown reason

Tags: html, css

I am creating a website under [experimental.danielhons.de](http://experimental.danielhons.de/index.php?page=Impressum) and have a problem when looking at it with small devices, like mobile devices or reducing the width of a browser window.

At some point, the page gets horizontally scrollable and on the right there is a whitespace.

Using Firebug, I see that it is the body-tag exceeding the screen, but I have used this css:

```
html, body {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

How can I prevent the page from being horizontally scrollable? [Screeshot with overflow:auto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiDzY.png)

Comment: I remember a similar issue a while ago. In my case it was the header image. You may want to consider providing a smaller pic for mobiles via the proper media query.

Comment: I use background-size:cover; so i hope this is not the problem.  --Checked that now: removing the image does not change the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Add this css

```
body {
   height: 100%;
   overflow: auto;
}

html {
   max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I used this block now in responsee.css, still no difference.

Comment: Remove your above css part

Comment: I did that, i replaced it with you css.

Comment: It was my fault, there was another definition in another css file. It is workling now, if i use overflow-x:hidden; but I still do not see what exactly is overlowing there

Comment: Set overflow: auto; when I do this its properly working

Comment: I do have auto now but still see a scrollbar. Is there any possibillity to see which element is overflowing?

Comment: Did you updated in this : http://experimental.danielhons.de/index.php?page=Impressum

Comment: Yes, i will attach a picture

Comment: It was only because i used "overflow: hidden", which does not seem to work with Safari on iOS. :-(

Answer (score 0):

I can clearly see that you have `overflow: scroll;` set on your body tag.
You can override only the x-axis specific rule by using `overflow-x:hidden;`.

[image]

Comment: You are right, removed the part in responsee.css now and replaced it in template-style.css, but still no difference.

Comment: @AsconX You dont need to remove anything, you can just override the existing CSS by applying a rule with higher precedence. Thats the beauty of it, the cascading effect.

Comment: Okay, but i will have to do some rework anyways and remove unused css. The template has a lot of stuff that i will not need anymore.