# Webpage x-scrollable on iOS Safari

Tags: html, css

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39746539/html-css-body-exceeds-screen-horizontally-for-unknown-reason/39746596?noredirect=1#comment66792918_39746596) yesterday where my page was scrollable horizontally for an unknown reason. Using `"overflow-x:hidden";` prevents the page from this (although I would prefer to know WHY and WHAT is overflowing).

Sadly this does not work on iOS Safari, where I can still scroll to the right.

[Here](http://experimental.danielhons.de/index.php?page=Impressum) is the Link to the site. I am using `overflow-x:auto;` at the moment because I hope someone might detect why there is any overflowing content at all, but also any idea how to handle mobile safari is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I checked in your site, and found that you have one element with `margin-right:5em;` so please write a media query for the mobile view and make it `0;`
change it in your `MyHeaders.css` line number 8

```
#companyName {
    font-size: 3em;
    margin-right: 5em;
}
```

change it to 0 in mobile view

Comment: use                                                                                                            @media (max-width:540px){                                             #companyName {
       margin-right: 0em;
}}

Comment: The companyName... now i see it.. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Add this meta on the header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Create a site wrapper `div` inside the `body` and apply the `overflow-x:hidden` to that wrapper INSTEAD of the `body` or `html` fixes the issue.

Comment: Great solution :) i will add this although the "bad element" (#companyName) is found and fixed.